# Qt Mac Checkboxes in List are cut off

Tags: macos, qt

I have a QListWidget and I want to have a checkbox next to each item.

When I fill the ListWidget with items:

```
QListWidgetItem *item;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    item = new QListWidgetItem();
    item->setText("Item");
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

the checkboxes are cut off, it looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I believe something else is wrong in your code, because part which you post looks fine to me, and QListWidget is something which can be consider to be pretty stable =). can you post a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current version of Qt, which only occurs on Macs with a Retina-Display. When the program is started in low-res, everything looks fine.